# I want one textbox to float left and other to float center, but both textboxes have same class

Tags: html, css

I have two textboxes which uses the same class (they both need to be the same class). But I want one textbox to float in the center and the other one to be float left, at the moment they are both float left. How can I achieve this?

Below are the two textboxes:

```
<input type="text" name="numberAnswer" class="numberAnswerTxt" onkeyup="numberKeyUp(this)" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onChange="getButtons()" >

<input type="text" name="numberAnswer" class="numberAnswerTxt" onkeyup="numberKeyUp(this)" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onChange="getButtons()" >
```

Below is the css of the class="numberAnswerTxt":

```
.numberAnswerTxt{
    float:left;
    width:40px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use different id's? something like:

```
<input type="text" id = "input1" name="numberAnswer" class="numberAnswerTxt" onkeyup="numberKeyUp(this)" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onChange="getButtons()" >
#input1 {
float:right;
etc..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for different IDs or multiple classes. Easy-peasy:

```
.numberAnswerTxt + .numberAnswerTxt {
    display: block; 
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[**More information about sibling selectors**](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector)
[**CSSDesk example**](http://cssdesk.com/aEKEk)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple classes for one Tag:

```
.size {
   width:900px;
   height:300px;
}

.background {
   background-color:red;
}

.leftfloat {
   float:left;
}
```

and:

```
<div class="size background leftfloat">BOX</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple classes.

```
<input type="text" name="numberAnswer" class="numberAnswerTxt floatLeft" onkeyup="numberKeyUp(this)" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onChange="getButtons()" >

<input type="text" name="numberAnswer" class="numberAnswerTxt" onkeyup="numberKeyUp(this)" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onChange="getButtons()" >

.numberAnswerTxt{
    width:40px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.floatLeft {
    float:left;
}
```